# How to use docker-compose to setup a mongodb with pymonogo app?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

I am trying to spin up a python application with mongodb server using docker-composer, but I get the following error:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

I really don't understand what am I missing in my setup:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
     - "9000:9000"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --smallfiles # --quiet    

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

I am not sure why I can't connect to the server which seems to be up (`docker ps`):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
fb5a00bb8867        composedir_web      "python app.py"          20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   composedir_web_1
56aeae245ad5        mongo:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago      Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                         mongodb
51c64650bab8        redis:alpine        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago      Up 21 seconds       6379/tcp                                         composedir_red
```

Comment: When you are "inside" a container `localhost` refers to the container itself, not the host.

Comment: @tgogos if I use robomonogo from the host with local host it works. Are you sure?

Comment: This works because you *publish* port `27017`. This practically means you are binding the `mongodb container port 27017` to your `host port 27017`. You have to configure your python container to talk to mongo by either using the container's IP or its name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the python application to connect mongo on `db:27017` instead of `localhost:27017`